# yum - how to install gpg key on ec2

Tags: amazon-ec2, debian, key, gnupg

I am deploying app on AWS serverless with ec2 instance and I got this error:

`W: GPG error: http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian jessie Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 7638D0442B90D010 NO_PUBKEY CBF8D6FD518E17E1`

So, I found that the solution might be to use gpg. And then I tried this:
`gpg --keyserver pgp.mit.edu --recv-keys 7638D0442B90D010 CBF8D6FD518E17E1`

The output was pretty fine I'd say:
`gpg: Total number processed: 2 gpg: imported: 2`

The next step is obviously saving somehow these keys and there I have a problem since I need to use yum instead of apt. I found suggestion to do this that way:

`gpg --armor --export 7638D0442B90D010; rpm --import /path/to/key`

And the issue is I have no idea what's the path. Do you maybe have easier way to fix this problem in general or can give me a hint how to work with yum keys path

Comment: Are you using RHEL or Debian. Rpm is RHEL tool, while Jessie is Debian version. Two different worlds.

Comment: I'm using the Debian one